# Passing child template to parent as parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to pass a child object to a function that takes the parent as a parameter through a templated function.

```
Parent* getParent( Parent* parent );
template<typename T>
T* getParent()
{
    return (T*) getParent( new T )
}
```

The `Parent* getParent( Parent* parent );` function only needs the `new T` in order to get information in the parent that the child classes set in their constructors. Is this bad practice/is there a better way via casting that this can be accomplished?

Before, I used a function like this:

```
Parent* getParent( ChildType type )
{
    //return requires the use of type
}
```

And it was called via

```
test.getParent<ChildClass>( ChildType::TYPE );
```

The first method posted now allows me to use this instead

```
test.getParent<ChildClass>();
```

Which is more straightforward as the `ChildClass` constructor initializes the `type` field in the `Parent` constructor

```
Parent* getParent( Parent* parent )
{
    ChildType type = parent->m_type;
    delete parent;
    //return using type
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Perhaps you can add more code to make it less confusing.

Comment: It is better that the one which allocates is the one which deallocates.

Comment: And avoid C-cast, prefer `static_cast`.

Comment: What is that last `getParent()` supposed to do?